# Find text accross mutiple lines to replace it with python (xml)

Tags: python, xml

I have the following XML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
    <Products>
        <item type="dict">
            <id type="int">37475</id>
            <name type="str">something_something</name>
            <slug type="str">something_something</slug>
            <permalink type="str">something_something</permalink>
            <date_created type="str">date</date_created>
            <date_created_gmt type="str">date</date_created_gmt>
            <date_modified type="str">date</date_modified>
            <date_modified_gmt type="str">date</date_modified_gmt>
            <type type="str">simple</type>
            <status type="str">publish</status>
            <featured type="bool">False</featured>
            <catalog_visibility type="str">visible</catalog_visibility>
            <description type="str">something_something</description> 
        </item>
```

I started with a JSON that I converted to a XML file so all of the products in that file start with the `<item type="dict">` tag, which is not what I want. I would like for all of the products to be enclosed in a `<product>` tag.

To fix this issue I am doing the following:

```
tree = ET.ElementTree(root)
        xmlstr = ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8', method='xml') #xml of each product to string so that it can be edited
        finalstr = xmlstr.decode("utf-8").replace(' />','') #remove wrong part
        finalstr = finalstr.replace('<item type="dict">     <id type="int">','<product>     <id type="int">')
```

This works for other problems in my XML file, but only when they are on one line.

My question is how do I select two or more lines so that I can replace them?

Desired output:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>
        <Products>
            <product>
                <id type="int">37475</id>
                <name type="str">something_something</name>
                <slug type="str">something_something</slug>
                <permalink type="str">something_something</permalink>
                <date_created type="str">date</date_created>
                <date_created_gmt type="str">date</date_created_gmt>
                <date_modified type="str">date</date_modified>
                <date_modified_gmt type="str">date</date_modified_gmt>
                <type type="str">simple</type>
                <status type="str">publish</status>
                <featured type="bool">False</featured>
                <catalog_visibility type="str">visible</catalog_visibility>
                <description type="str">something_something</description> 
            </product>
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit more code in order to make this a minimal reproducible example? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Use `"` instead of `'` and add `\n` where you want a line break.

Comment: Sure thing, apologises for not doing that.

Comment: @wuerfelfreak, why use " instead?

Comment: Because with `'` there will be no linebreak but just the literals backslash and n. Only text inbetween `"` is escaped. Text inbetween `'` is taken as is.

Comment: Should the \n be out of the quotations?

Comment: no, inside quotations

Comment: It is better to use XSLT transformation for your scenario. Also, please edit your question, and add a desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be possible with regular expression:

```
finalstr = re.sub('<item type="dict">[\n\s]*<id type="int">','<product>\n<id type="int">', finalstr)
```

This will allow you to select more than one line (notice the `[\n\s]*` part between xml nodes - this will select lines with any amount of new lines or whitespaces inbetween)

Read more about `re.sub` here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the XSLT for the scenario. It is following so called **modified identity transform** pattern.

If there is a need for the XML prolog, just modify `omit-xml-declaration="yes"` as `omit-xml-declaration="no"`.

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity template -->
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item">
        <product>
            <xsl:apply-templates />
        </product>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```